# Airflow not creating meta tables

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm quite new to Airflow, but managed to run it locally (with SQLite) following the docs.

Given that I need some additional tools I tried to put everything into a Docker, but I'm failing to do so.

I removed everything that was added but still can't find the issue.
I then followed this [tutorial #1](https://towardsdatascience.com/apache-airflow-and-postgresql-with-docker-and-docker-compose-5651766dfa96) downgrading the version of the file from 3.8 to 3.3 and removing the restart policy; but I can't even reach port 8080.

Digging a little further, I found this [tutorial #2](https://xnuinside.medium.com/quick-guide-how-to-run-apache-airflow-cluster-in-docker-compose-615eb8abd67a), that then allowed me to reach port 8080, but when I try to create an user using command line it returns an error from the database telling me that no table called log or dags exists. Creating the user via UI works fine, but it seems odd to me that the db don't see this (I checked for the db container logs).

A small example is the following docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  airflow:
  image: apache/airflow
```

Running `docker-compose up` and then `docker-compose run airflow db check`, I get

```
[2021-02-08 21:55:06,865] {cli_action_loggers.py:105} WARNING - Failed to log action with (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: log
[SQL: INSERT INTO log (dttm, dag_id, task_id, event, execution_date, owner, extra) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('2021-02-08 21:55:06.862078', None, None, 'cli_check', None, 'airflow', '{"host_name": "b9b6f084640f", "full_command": "[\'/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow\', \'db\', \'check\']"}')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
[2021-02-08 21:55:06,866] {db.py:756} INFO - Connection successful.
```

I then proceeded with `docker-compose run airflow db init` and there were only two warnings

```
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/ddl/sqlite.py:44 UserWarning: Skipping unsupported ALTER for creation of implicit constraintPlease refer to the batch mode feature which allows for SQLite migrations using a copy-and-move strategy.
```

And the webserver `docker-compose run airflow webserver -p 8080`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: dag

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dag
[SQL: SELECT dag.dag_id AS dag_dag_id, dag.root_dag_id AS dag_root_dag_id, dag.is_paused AS dag_is_paused, dag.is_subdag AS dag_is_subdag, dag.is_active AS dag_is_active, dag.last_scheduler_run AS dag_last_scheduler_run, dag.last_pickled AS dag_last_pickled, dag.last_expired AS dag_last_expired, dag.scheduler_lock AS dag_scheduler_lock, dag.pickle_id AS dag_pickle_id, dag.fileloc AS dag_fileloc, dag.owners AS dag_owners, dag.description AS dag_description, dag.default_view AS dag_default_view, dag.schedule_interval AS dag_schedule_interval, dag.concurrency AS dag_concurrency, dag.has_task_concurrency_limits AS dag_has_task_concurrency_limits, dag.next_dagrun AS dag_next_dagrun, dag.next_dagrun_create_after AS dag_next_dagrun_create_after 
FROM dag 
WHERE dag.is_active = 1 OR dag.is_paused = 1]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

Had someone had prior experience with this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed by https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13921 and will be released in **Airflow 2.0.1** later today.

For now, you can just delete the `airflow.db` if it does not contain any important data. And re-run the docker-compose file or `airflow db upgrade`.

Comment: I couldn't find airflow.db file. I assumed it'd follow the local installation logic, but couldn't find anything in $AIRFLOW_HOME nor in /home/airflow. Could you tell where I can find it ?

Comment: yet another thing, if I may: I noticed the PR fixes it for SQLite, but even when setting up with Postgre, as per the second link in the question, I got the exact same error. Are they related ?

Comment: Use the instructions in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html to use docker-compose

Comment: I had to change only apache/airflow:2.0.1 to apache/airflow, but both airflow-webserver/scheduler keeps restarting with the same "No table called log". Can't still find the airflow.db file, it seems it's not being created at all. Any cues?

Comment: Did you use thee docker-compose I linked, it should called `db upgrade` which will use Postgres, `airflow.db` would only be created when using sqlite

Comment: Yes, I used and it didn't work. It seems I forgot to manually add an airflow.cfg file to be shipped with the container